# Upgrade 11.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, upgrade, update-manager, disk

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. My computer is no longer supported and my computer is now trying to get me to upgrade to 12.10. But I want to upgrade to 12.**04**. Can I upgrade to 12.04 using the update manager  or do I have to use a bootable disk? And will it be fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 possible ways:

1. You can download the Ubuntu 12.04 ISO-Image an use this for upgrade.
2. You can set the update-manager to check for LTS-Versions. You find an options button in the Update Manager and select the tab Update, in the bottom should be a list, which versions should be checked.

Comment: Ok, but do I need to have certain hardware? And will it be ok?

Comment: I don't know your hardware, but I think, if Ubuntu 11.04 runs 12.04 should also run. You can check the minimum requirements on the website https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 1):

You need the bootable disk, or at least the ISO file locally.

---

Online (using Update Manager), you can only 'upgrade' to 12.04 (from 11.04) after first installing 11.10 ..